# Can the MSVC linker be configured to show const volatile variables in the *.map file

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

I'm investigating the possibility of using XCP on windows. 
For those not familiar, it's as simple as sending the address of a variable to the application via a communication channel, like sockets and asking it to modify or send you the variable on that location.

The good new is that I was able to read and change normal volatile and non volatile variables this way. 
For this I search the map file for the address of the variable and when receiving the address in the application, the offset of the segment in it's virtual memory is added.

The problem with const volatile variables is that they do not appear in the map file.

Can someone explain me why this is and how to make them appear in the map file anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try another compiler system like GCC? Is the variable read at all, or might the compiler optimize it away?

Comment: I thought it could be optimized. I can put a breakpoint and change the variable though. I have not yet tried another compiler on Windows.

Comment: I tried with GCC, and the variables is in the `.data` section, as expected. Since I don't use Microsoft's compiler (for good reasons), I can't help you further.

Answer (score 1):

I was investigating another topic and stumbled on this one.  You may be interested in this XCP implementation.  https://github.com/vectorgrp/XCPlite  There is also another XCP Sample Implementation at https://www.vector.com/int/en/download/xcp-sample-implementation-1305/ that is worthwhile.  Both can be compiled and run on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. We now use the info from the pdb file to get the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I found the setting that makes const and const volatile variables show up in the map file.

To enable it right click on the project and select properties.
Linker>Optimization>Link Time Code Generation must be set to "Use Link Time Code Generation(/LTCG)".

I don't yet know what the setting means though, but it solved my problem and what I'm trying to do now works.